# Combinatorial question for wait times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A call centre agent has a 70% chance of reaching a customer they dial, and if they do connect then the total call time is 5 minutes. In the 30% chance that they are unable to connect with customer, they would have wasted 30 seconds to dial and wait for someone to pick up.

How many customer conversations are expected in a 1 hour period? (note: it doesn't have to be an integer since if there's 2 minutes left in the hour and an agent connects, that counts as 2/5 of a customer conversation).

Comment: I would let $X_t$ represent the number of customer conversations on $[0,t]$ where $t$ is in minutes, and $f(t)=\mathbb{E}(X_t)$. You're trying to find $f(60)$. Note $f(t)=0.7$ for any $t\in [0,1/2]$. Also, 
 $$\begin{eqnarray*}f(t)&=& \mathbb{E}(X_t|\text{First call answered})\mathbb{P}(\text{First call answered})+\mathbb{E}(X_t|\text{First call ignored})\mathbb{P}(\text{First call ignored}) \\ &=& \left(1+f(t-5)\right)\times 0.7 + f(t-1/2)\times 0.3\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: You can iterate this expression starting at $t=60$ to get you expected number of calls. There may be an easier way, but this is what first came to my mind.

Comment: I should have written $[0,1/2)$ instead of $[0,1/2]$ in my first comment.